# Electron freezes when sending large object synchronously over ipc

Tags: javascript, ipc, electron

When trying to send large(ish) objects synchronously over ipc, Electron freezes: the view goes blank and I get a message saying "DevTools was disconnected from the page". Is there a sensible way of sending large objects sync'd, or do I have to go async?

Just for reference, the length of the JSON stringified form of the object is 72760484 characters.

Comment: Could you use the file system? Write the content to a temporary file, pass the path via ipc, reload on the other side, and delete the temp file?

Comment: An async approach (block based or web worker] would be able to solve this as this is caused by a blocking operation which due to timeout triggers the underlying browser engine.

Comment: @ShawnRakowski That would probably work, but I think all in all would be a more complex solution than using asynchronous ipc.

Comment: @K3N I don't think it's a timeout issue. The freeze happens immediately when I return the data from the event handler, there's no noticeable delay.

Answer (score -2):

Electron IPC was not designed for sending large amounts of data like this. IPC blocks all processes so the hanging is what you would expect.